# C: PThread_create Parsing Char[] parameter to function

Tags: c

Hallo All,

I have this method:

```
void *readFileLocal(char filename[]){
       .....
}
```

Now i want to start this method a a thread:

```
char input[strlen(argv[1])];
strcpy(input,argv[1]);
pthread_t read,write;
pthread_create(&read, NULL, &readFileLocal, &input);
```

But during compilation it gives this warning:

```
file.c:29: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type
```

/usr/include/pthread.h:227: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(char *)’

How can I parse an char array to my funcation over pthread_create without this warning ?
Thanks for helpt

Answer (score 3):

Just use this:

```
pthread_create(&read, NULL, readFileLocal, input);
```

And consider changing your function's signature to:

```
void *readFileLocal(void *fileName) { }
```

When you are passing a pointer to function (like the one you are using in `readFileLocal` parameter) you don't need to put  `&`.

Also, when you have an array (like `input` in your case) you don't need `&` since in **C** arrays can be used as pointers already.

Comment: C arrays are _not_ pointers, they just tend to decay into pointers at the slightest provocation.

Comment: @Hasturkun: Agree. I don't think it is relevant to the question though.

Comment: It isn't really, except for furthering the strange myth claiming that arrays are pointers

Answer (score 2):

Functions for threads need to be prototyped:

```
void *func(void *argv);
```

As with all void pointers you then need to interpret ("cast") the pointer to a meaningful entity. You readFileLocal functions then becomes:

```
void *readFileLocal(void *argv)
{
    char *fname = argv; // Cast to string
    // Rest of func
}
```

Comment: +1 for "casting" without the cast operator. The operation is called "convert": there are implicit conversions (done by the compiler without the cast) and explicit conversions (done with the cast operator).